# Is quasivariety generated by all perfect graphs finitely axiomatizable?

Tags: lo.logic, model-theory, universal-algebra

Fix logic $L$ with equality and a binary relation symbol $E$.

The class of graphs can be identified with the class of models of the universal first-order Horn $L$-sentences $\forall x,y\; E(x,y) \rightarrow E(y,x)$ and $\forall x\; \lnot E(x,x)$.  Note that this class includes infinite graphs.

An odd hole is a cycle with an odd number of vertices, at least five.  An odd antihole is the complement of an odd hole.  A Berge graph contains no induced odd holes or antiholes.  By the Strong Perfect Graph theorem, a graph is perfect iff it is Berge.  It is therefore possible to define the class of perfect graphs as the finite models of an infinite set of universal first-order sentences, each expressing a property "this graph does not contain an odd (anti)hole of order $2k+3$", for $k=1,2,\dots$.  Call the class of all models of this set of sentences the $\omega$-perfect graphs (to highlight the fact that it may include infinite structures).

My primary question:

> Is the class of $\omega$-perfect graphs finitely axiomatizable?

One could conclude this if the class of all $L$-structures that are not $\omega$-perfect were axiomatizable, but if this is the case then it is not obvious to me.

<strike>Further, the direct product of two perfect graphs is again perfect (for instance, this is an immediate corollary of a theorem of Ravindra and Parthasarathy).  Since the class of $\omega$-perfect graphs can be axiomatized by a set of universal sentences, it is closed under ultraproducts.  Hence the class of $\omega$-perfect graphs is closed under isomorphism, substructures (induced subgraphs), direct products, and ultraproducts, and therefore is a quasivariety definable by a set of universal (first-order) Horn sentences of $L$.  (Although their existence seems guaranteed, justifying the title of this question, I don't actually know an explicit set of universal Horn axioms for the $\omega$-perfect graphs.)  If the answer to the main question is affirmative, then this leads to the follow-on question:</strike>

> Is the class of $\omega$-perfect graphs finitely axiomatizable by universal Horn sentences?

*Edit:* Thanks to bof for pointing out that if $G$ is $C_5$ with an edge added, then $G \times G$ is not perfect!  I misinterpreted the result, the correct one is (in modern notation):

> ([Ravindra and Parthasarathy 1977](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0012-365X(77)90056-5), Theorem 3.2) $G_1 \times G_2$ is perfect iff either
>   1. $G_1$ or $G_2$ is bipartite, or
>   2. $G_1$ and $G_2$ are both [(odd-hole,paw)-free](http://www.graphclasses.org/classes/AUTO_736.html).

The quasivariety generated by the $\omega$-perfect graphs therefore includes many non-perfect finite graphs.  To match the question title, my second question should therefore be:

> Is the quasivariety generated by all perfect graphs finitely axiomatizable?

Comment: If the class is axiomatizable by universal Horn sentences, and if it's finitely axiomatizable, then it's finitely axiomatizable by Horn sentences; this follows from the compactness theorem. However, the class of perfect graphs is not closed under direct product. Let $G$ be the graph obtained by adding one more edge to the cycle $C_5$.Then $G$ is perfect, but the direct product $G\times G$ is easily seen to contain $C_5$ as an induced subgraph. so it's not perfect. Many different products of graphs are considered in graph theory; maybe the theorem you cited is about some other graph product?

Answer (score 3):

Let $\sigma_k$ be a first-order sentence expressing the property "this graph does not contain an odd hole or antihole of order $2k+3$". If the theory of "$\omega$-perfect" graphs (I'd just call them perfect graphs) were finitely axiomatizable, then finitely many of the sentences $\sigma_k$ would imply all the rest of them. This is not the case, because for each $n$ the graph $C_{2n+3}$ satisfies $\sigma_k$ for all $k\ne n$.

Comment: I don't follow your implication that the finite set of axioms could be chosen from among the $\sigma_k$'s.  Could you provide a hint?

Comment: @AndrásSalamon: Since the $\sigma_k$ are a complete axiomatization, they prove the purported finite axiomatization. Such a proof uses only finitely many of the $\sigma_k$, which together form a complete axiomatization.

Comment: @François G. Dorais: thanks!  Clearly my model theory is even rustier than I thought.